# How do I change the .NET Framework from version 3.5 to version 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have created a class library in .NET Framework 3.5. Now I want to change the .NET Framework Version to 4.0.

How can I do this?

Comment: Change Target framework to 4.0 in VS/Project Properties & compile

Comment: Make sure you have version 4 installed.

Answer (score 43):

In Visual Studio:

1. Right-click on your project
2. Select Properties
3. Select the Application tab
4. Change the Target Framework to the desired framework

If you are not seeing **.NET Framework 4** as an option there, ensure you have it installed.

For completeness, one can also point an existing DLL to a later version of the .NET Framework without recompiling using [Binding Redirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on the project in the solution explorer and select **Properties**.
2. Make sure that the **Application** tab is selected.
3. In the **Target framework** dropdown select the desired framework, e.g. **.NET Framework 4**.

Answer (score 1):

In **Visual Studio 2010**:

1. **Right-click** on your **Project**
2. Select **Properties**
3. Select the **Compile** tab
4. At the bottom, select **Advanced Compile Options**
5. Change the **Target Framework** to the desired framework

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot be done once a .dll has been created. For this you need to have source of your class library.

- Select **Properties** from Right clicking on the project in the solution explorer.
- In **Application Tab** change **Target Framework** to **Desired one**.

Comment: Actually, if you don't have source you can still use binding redirects to utilize a later version of the .NET framework (they are backwards compatible) or even an earlier version if the binary makes no use of features not in the earlier version.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

FYI - there's a "Target Framework Migrator" extension tool for Visual Studio (2013, 2015) that will do all projects in your solution in one go.

I'm working on a solution at the moment with a 100+ projects in it and it's not practicable to do each project one at a time IMO.