# Unable to add references in Visual studio 2019 Preview and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

I want to add Microsof Sharepoint references ,currently i am having 3.0 .Net  Framework.
I followed below steps to add New Framwework :

Click 'Project' menu
Click 'Add Reference' sub menu
Click 'Browse...' button
In the file name texbox, paste : 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0' (or any other framework version)
But i couldn't find 4.0 ,only 3.0 is there . I thought SharePoint reference is there in 4.0. 
Please guide me in installing the SharePoint framework and adding it as reference.

Comment: Are you trying to add a reference or change the target framework of your project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the .Net Framework from version 3.5 to version 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877913/how-do-i-change-the-net-framework-from-version-3-5-to-version-4-0)

Comment: How do you add the Sharepoint references? I suggest that you can install- nuget package -Microsoft.SharePoint to see if you can install the correct reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Update .Net version of your Solution**

If you need to update the .Net version, go to the properties of the project and under Application, change the version of the 'Target Framework'.

Comment: I Can only see upto 3.0 ,i can't see 4.0 there , how to install and add . I want to add SharePoint reference actually.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=17718 - download and install.. then update the framework.